# MVVM Saving value Picker trigers once the page is open

Tags: xamarin

I have picker this is my ViewModel.Everything works, the only issue is that the Toast is triggered once the page is open? So it seems that everytime i open the page i am saving new data.

```
private List<TimeoutBetweenSentences> _sentencePause = new List<TimeoutBetweenSentences>();
private TimeoutBetweenSentences _selectedSentencePause;
public List<TimeoutBetweenSentences> SentencePause
        {
            get => _sentencePause;
            set => SetProperty(ref _sentencePause, value);
        }

        public TimeoutBetweenSentences SelectedSentencePause
        {
            get => _selectedSentencePause;
            set
            {
                this.IsBusy = true;
                SetProperty(ref _selectedSentencePause, value);
               NotificationService.ShowToast("Please wait, we are saving");

                UserSettings newSetting = new UserSettings()
                {
                    DateSaved = DateTime.Now,
                    OptionId = (int)SettingOption.TimeoutBetweenSentences,
                    Value = value.Position.ToString()
                };

                new Thread(new ThreadStart(async () =>
                {

                    await LangUpDataSaverLoader.SaveUserSettings(newSetting);
                    LangUpDataSaverLoader.LoadUserSettingsAndFillAppValues();
                })).Start();

                this.IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
```

Load saved data

```
        _sentencePause = FillTimoutOptions();
        var posTim = _sentencePause.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Value == LangUpUserCustomSettings.TimeoutBetweenEnglishSentences);

        if (posTim != null)
        {
            _selectedSentencePause = posTim;
        }



 public Settings()
        {


            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new SettingsViewModel();

        }
```

my xaml

```
<Picker 
                                x:Name="sentencePausesStepper"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding SentencePause}"
                                WidthRequest="300" 
                                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Text}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSentencePause, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    FontSize="20"
                    grial:PickerProperties.BorderStyle="Default"
                    TextColor= "{ DynamicResource ListViewItemTextColor }"
                     BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    Title="{ grial:Translate A_PickerSetYourPauseEng }">
                            </Picker>
```

Do you have any idea what could be causing this? I need the event to be fired once the user will change the item not when the page is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could invoke the code in **set** method only when the value **SelectedSentencePause** been changed .

```
public TimeoutBetweenSentences SelectedSentencePause
        {
            get => _selectedSentencePause;
            set
            {
                if(_selectedSentencePause!=value&&_selectedSentencePause!=null)
                {

                  this.IsBusy = true;
                SetProperty(ref _selectedSentencePause, value);
               NotificationService.ShowToast("Please wait, we are saving");

                UserSettings newSetting = new UserSettings()
                {
                    DateSaved = DateTime.Now,
                    OptionId = (int)SettingOption.TimeoutBetweenSentences,
                    Value = value.Position.ToString()
                };

                new Thread(new ThreadStart(async () =>
                {

                    await LangUpDataSaverLoader.SaveUserSettings(newSetting);
                    LangUpDataSaverLoader.LoadUserSettingsAndFillAppValues();
                })).Start();

                this.IsBusy = false;
                }

            }
        }
```